# how to create audio captcha's in android?

Tags: android

how to create audio captcha's in android???
I want to audio captcha in android.But i am unable to get any code related to audi captcha.I am using recaptcha to create captcha in my android app.in the similar way i want audio based captcha also.But unable to get audio based captcha???or how to captcha text??

I tried follwing code:

## CaptchaActivity.java

```
public class CaptchaActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener, OnVerifyAnswerListener, OnShowChallengeListener{

     private static final String PUBLIC_KEY  = "6LcPWugSAAAAAC-MP5sg6wp_CQiyxHvPvkQvVlVf";
        private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "6LcPWugSAAAAALWMp-gg9QkykQQyO6ePBSUk-Hjg";

        private ReCaptcha   reCaptcha;
        private ProgressBar progress;
        private EditText    answer;
        private ActionBar actionbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_captcha);

        getActionBarHeader();
        speech();

           this.reCaptcha = (ReCaptcha)this.findViewById(R.id.recaptcha);
            this.progress  = (ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            this.answer    = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.answer);

            this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(this);
            this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setOnClickListener(this);

            this.showChallenge();

    }
      private void getActionBarHeader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.blue)));

            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

            View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.maintitle, null);

            TextView header = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.apptitle);
            header.setText(Html
                    .fromHtml("<font color=#ffffff>REGISTER</font>"));

            actionbar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
            actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
        public void onChallengeShown(final boolean shown) {
            this.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (shown) {
                // If a CAPTCHA is shown successfully, displays it for the user to enter the words
                this.reCaptcha.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnswerVerified(final boolean success) {
            if (success) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "verification_success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"verification_failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // (Optional) Shows the next CAPTCHA
            this.showChallenge();
        }

        private void showChallenge() {
            // Displays a progress bar while downloading CAPTCHA
            this.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.reCaptcha.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            this.reCaptcha.showChallengeAsync(CaptchaActivity.PUBLIC_KEY, this);


        }

        private void verifyAnswer() {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(this.answer.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "instruction", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Displays a progress bar while submitting the answer for verification
                this.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.reCaptcha.verifyAnswerAsync(CaptchaActivity.PRIVATE_KEY, this.answer.getText().toString(), this);
            }
        }






        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               switch (v.getId()) {
               case R.id.imageView2:
                 //  this.verifyAnswer();
                  // speech();

                   if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED||result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA){
                       Toast.makeText(CaptchaActivity.this, "device not suippporttedd", 500).show();
                   }
                   else{
                       speeches.speak("kallyani i am",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                   }
                   break;

               case R.id.imageView1:
                   this.showChallenge();

                   break;
           }
        }
        TextToSpeech speeches;
        int result;
    private void speech() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    speeches=new TextToSpeech(CaptchaActivity.this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    result=speeches.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(CaptchaActivity.this, "device not suippporttedd", 500).show();
                }
            }
        });
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.captcha, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```